# React Router v6 <Navigation /> showing blank page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following code in my router.tsx file:

```
<Route path='/portal/edit' element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
    {props.editObject != null &&
        <Route path='/portal/edit' element={<Edit
            editObject={props.editObject}
        />}/>
    }
    {props.editObject == null &&
        <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/portal/overview" />} />
    }
</Route>
```

**What is the code doing?**
First, I am checking if the User is Authenticated. If the user is authenticated we are checking if the prop `editObject` is null or not. The user is not allowed to enter the page when editObject is null. If the object is null I want to redirect back to 'overview'.

Any route works except the `<Navigation />`-links. I checked in the debugger and the code is going to `<Navigate replace...` but the browser is showing me only a blank page without any useful information in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

> ```
> <Route path='/portal/edit' element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
>   {props.editObject != null &&
>     <Route path='/portal/edit' element={<Edit
>       editObject={props.editObject}
>     />}/>
>   }
>   {props.editObject == null &&
>     <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/portal/overview" />} />
>   }
> </Route>
> ```

The issue here is that route paths that don't start with a leading `"/"` character are considered to be relative paths. The nested `Route` with `path="*"` resolves to a path like `"/portal/edit/*"`. I suspect you should have seen a "no route matches....." type warning in the console.

## Solution

It seems you are basically conditionally rendering the `element` prop, i.e. either the routed `Edit` or `Navigate` component.

An optimized suggestion. Keep the outer `PrivateRoute` as a layout component but remove the `path` prop so the inner routes can do the matching. Render the inner route and conditionally render either the `Edit` or `Navigate` redirect.

```
<Route element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
  <Route
    path='/portal/edit'
    element={props.editObject !== null
      ? <Edit editObject={props.editObject} />
      : <Navigate replace to="/portal/overview" />
    }
  />
</Route>
```

Comment: Thx for explanation. But I really did not get the "no route matches....." console-message. I think changing <Route PrivateRoute/> to a non-path would lead to unnecessary arithmetic operations, since react would check the PrivateRoute every time route.tsx was called, even if the path was a completely different one. Without specifying the path in PrivateRoute, it would always go in there. Example: <Route element={<PrivateRoute/>} <Route path 'OneWay'....
<Route element={<PrivateRoute/>}
<Route path='anotherWay'...
This code would now run PrivateRoute two times

Comment: @Paul The `Routes` component reads all the children routes and builds up a tree structure with all the paths, so it knows what will match and need to hit that `PrivateRoute` component even though you didn't explicitly declare a `path` prop for it. Regarding the `"no route matches....." console-message` bit, that's a warning you'll see if you navigate to `"/test"` for example, but you didn't declare any `Route` components to match *that* path.